# i created a table in database to display photos and i made it to display ,but i want them to display from the last to the first

Tags: mysql, sorting

```
<?php


$conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if(!$conn){
echo mysql_error();
}

$db = mysql_select_db("imagestore",$conn);
if(!$db ){
echo mysql_error();
}



$q = "SELECT * FROM imagetable";
$r = mysql_query("$q",$conn);



if($r)
{
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($r) )  
   {

   header("Content-type: text/html");
   echo "</br>";
   echo $row['photoname'];
   echo "</br>";

   $type = "Content-type: ".$row['phototype'];
   header($type);

   echo "<img src=image.php?fotoid=". $row['fotoid']."width =300 height =              35.     300/>";

}
}
else{

   echo mysql_error();
}


 ?>
```

Comment: The SQL clause you're looking for is `ORDER BY`.  Use it to sort the records when you select them from the database.

Comment: Why does your question sums up your code? (Line numbers..), can you please use the [right formatting](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Answer (score 0):

I know `ORDER` by but is not working to display photos as i want in my page .
I am a beginner .
I used `$q = "SELECT * FROM imagetable ORDER BY fotoid DESC";`